# Grammatical function of "secret" in "It's a story they've kept secret for a decade."

Tags: usage, adverbs

Does *secret* in this context:

> It's a story they've kept **secret** for a decade.

play the role of an adverb? If so why does no dictionary defines it as such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of a similar sentence:

> They've kept a story secret for a decade.

The grammar here is clearly explained by the dictionary, just under ["keep"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/keep): the verb is used "with object and complement". The object is "a story" and "secret" is an [object complement](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar/grammar-rules-and-tips/what-is-a-complement-in-grammar.html) because it describes the object. An object complement can be an adjective, a noun, or a phrase that functions like an adjective or noun. Here "secret" is an adjective because it lacks an article ("a secret" is what it would be if it was a noun).

Why your sentence is ordered differently than mine is because it uses an [*it*-cleft](http://folk.uio.no/hhasselg/terms.html#it-cleft).

Answer (score 2):

It's an adjective here.

Compare the following, which have the same structure:

- It's a story they've kept **private** for a decade
- It's a story they made **public** a long time ago
- It's a machine they've kept **clean** for a decade

First definition from OED:

**secret A.** *adj.*  **1.** Kept from knowledge or observation; hidden, concealed.  **a.** Predicatively (esp. in **to keep secret**): Kept from public knowledge, or from the knowledge of persons specified; not allowed to be known, or only by selected persons.